# How to get in returnUrl AccessDeniedPath in ASP.NET MVC 6 (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I use the latest version of ASP.NET MVC 6.

The following settings are set `Startup.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/error/accessdenied");
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = false;
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

In the `Account` Controller has action `Login`

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

In the method above I have no problem getting `returnUrl`.

Also in the controller `Error` has action `AccessDenied`

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AccessDenied(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

But when the user has no permission to access the pages of the site, the system forwards the user to a page `../error/accessdenied`.

At the moment, after I get redirected `returnUrl` value is `null`.

Can I get the address of the page from which the user was redirected (as well as it works for `LoginPath`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it will be shipped in the RC2, take a look at the CookieAuthorizationHandler.HandleForbiddenAsync method source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs),

```
protected override async Task<bool> HandleForbiddenAsync(ChallengeContext context)
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(context.Properties);
    var returnUrl = properties.RedirectUri;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        returnUrl = OriginalPathBase + Request.Path + Request.QueryString;
    }
    var accessDeniedUri = Options.AccessDeniedPath + QueryString.Create(Options.ReturnUrlParameter, returnUrl);
    var redirectContext = new CookieRedirectContext(Context, Options, BuildRedirectUri(accessDeniedUri), properties);
    await Options.Events.RedirectToAccessDenied(redirectContext);
    return true;
}
```

You can have a feedback on how to migrate from RC1 to RC2 on the [Home repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1381).